# How to retrieve SVGPath content from MouseEvent in JavaFX

Tags: svg, javafx

I am working on a project that allows users to click a state in the U.S., which then displays a quiz that asks what the state and the capital are. The states are SVGPaths. I need the mouse event handler to determine which SVGPath was clicked on in order to determine the quiz data. How can I pull the coordinates of the SVGPath that was clicked on from the handler?

```
        //Mouse event handler for attacking states 
      EventHandler<MouseEvent> clickState = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         @Override 
         public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
            /*
             * Register quiz data here
             * 
             * QuizScreenController.setState(state);
             * QuizScreenController.setCapital(capital)
             */

             //Load quiz screen
            loadQuiz("State Quiz");
         }

      }; 
      //allStates is an SVGPath array that stores the individual state paths
      for(SVGPath currState : allStates) {  
          //Color states
          currState.setFill(Color.GRAY);
          registerHandler(currState, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK);  
          //Register mouse event
          currState.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, clickState);
      }
```

Comment: You have access to the `MouseEvent` whose source will be the `SVGPath` which you can then query, in this case. The event also gives to access to the local, scene, and screen (x,y) coordinates of the mouse when clicked. What do you want to do with these coordinates? If you want to determine which state the path is, you could always create an enum of states and set the [user data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setUserData(java.lang.Object)) on each appropriate path.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm not very fluent in Java and I wasn't familiar with enumerations or how to properly query a MouseEvent. I found my own solution, but I will look into what you said as a more efficient method for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm pretty sure this wasn't the most efficient way to do this, I was able to pull the necessary data by setting the MouseEvent inside of the EventFilter. This way, I was able to simply pass the current path iteration of the foreach loop into the event.

```
for(SVGPath currState : allStates) {  
              //Color states
              currState.setFill(Color.GRAY);
              registerHandler(currState, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK);

              //Register mouse click
              currState.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                 @Override 
                 public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                     //Set quiz data
                    if(currState.getContent().equals(washington)) {
                      QuizScreenController.setState("washington");
                      QuizScreenController.setCapital("seattle");
                      selectedState = currState;
                  } else if(currState.getContent().equals(california)) {
                      QuizScreenController.setState("california");
                      QuizScreenController.setCapital("sacramento");
                    selectedState = currState;
                  }
```